# How do I get rid of the big empty space in an ASP.NET gridview with no data?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I built a custom gridview that allows for a fixed number of rows, so that on a 10 entry count page has only 2 rows of data, it will generate 8 extra empty rows.  This works even when there is no data at all.  It generates 10 empty rows.  As it should.  Its great

BUT... if there is no data it also appends this huge empty space below my 10 empty rows.  I believe its the normal space that is supposed to be generated when no data is bound to the gridview, but I don't want it.  How do i get rid of that?

Here is part of the markup:

```
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlGrdCustomers" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%" CssClass="srcColor">            
        <X:GridViewX ID="gvxTaskList" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDsbyStatus"
            Width="100%" Height="100%" CssClass="tablestyle" OnRowCreated="gvxTaskList_RowCreated">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrowstyle" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerstyle" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="rowstyle" Wrap="false" />  

            <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="#edf5ff" Height="300px" VerticalAlign="Middle" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <EmptyDataTemplate >
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketId" HeaderText="TicketId" SortExpression="TicketId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TicketCreated" HeaderText="TicketCreated" SortExpression="TicketCreated" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactName" HeaderText="ContactName" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ContactName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CompanyName" HeaderText="CompanyName" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="CompanyName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Status" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Priority" HeaderText="Priority" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Priority" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="AssignedTo" HeaderText="AssignedTo" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="AssignedTo" />
            </Columns>
        </X:GridViewX>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDSbyStatus" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EnterpriseConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT scT.TicketId, scT.TicketCreated, 
        (SELECT scCon.ContactName FROM scContacts scCon WHERE scCon.AccountId = scT.AccountId AND scT.ContactId = scCon.ContactId) AS 'ContactName', 
        (SELECT Name FROM scCompanies WHERE scT.AccountId = AccountId AND CompanyId = 
            (SELECT scCon.CompanyId FROM scContacts scCon WHERE scCon.AccountId = scT.AccountId AND scT.ContactId = scCon.ContactId)) AS 'CompanyName', 
        scT.Description, 
        (SELECT scStat.Description FROM scStatuses scStat WHERE scT.AccountId = scStat.AccountId AND scT.StatusId = scStat.StatusId) AS 'Status', 
        (SELECT scPri.Description FROM scPriorities scPri WHERE scT.AccountId = scPri.AccountId AND scT.PriorityId = scPri.PriorityId) AS 'Priority', 
        (SELECT (FirstName + ' ' + LastName) FROM Users WHERE scT.UserId = UserId) AS 'AssignedTo'
        FROM scTickets scT 
        WHERE scT.AccountId = @1 AND StatusId = @2 Order By TicketCreated ASC">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="1" Type="Int64" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="2" Type="Int16"/>
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is some of the code behind for it:
        public partial class TestForm : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration webcfg = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/configuration");

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Task List page loads with all open tickets
        SqlDSbyStatus.SelectParameters.Clear();
        SqlDSbyStatus.SelectParameters.Add("1", TypeCode.Int64, "3");
        SqlDSbyStatus.SelectParameters.Add("2", TypeCode.Int64, "1");   

        hidPageIndex.Value = gvxTaskList.PageIndex.ToString();
        hidRowCount.Value = gvxTaskList.unmodifiedRowCount.ToString();
        hidLastPage.Value = gvxTaskList.isLastPage.ToString();
    }

    protected void gvxTaskList_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        string rowID = String.Empty;

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {                
            rowID = "row" + e.Row.RowIndex;
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("id", "row" + e.Row.RowIndex);
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "ChangeRowColor(" + "'" + rowID + "'" + ")");                           
        }
    }
```

And finally the gridview code I overrode:

```
namespace GridViewX
{
    [Description("Represents a custom GridView that creates additional empty rows to fill a fixed-row grid.")]
    [ToolboxData("<{0}:GridViewX runat=server></{0}:GridViewX>")]
public class GridViewX : System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView
{
    protected override void OnDataBound(EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvRow = null;

        isLastPage = (this.PageIndex + 1 == this.PageCount) ? true : false;
        unmodifiedRowCount = this.Rows.Count;

        for (int rows = this.Rows.Count; rows < this.PageSize; rows++)
        {
            gvRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);

            for (int columns = 0; columns < this.Columns.Count; columns++)
            {
                gvRow.Controls.Add(new TableCell());
            }

            //Inserts the rows right above the footer row. 
            //Remove the "- 1" if you are not using a footer.
            this.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(this.Controls[0].Controls.Count - 1, gvRow);
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Ok added the code.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem by utilizing the EmptyDataTemplate tag, filling it with a simple no data message, then modifying the code of my custom gridview to do a check to see if there was no data like so:

```
protected override void OnDataBound(EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvRow = null;

    isLastPage = (this.PageIndex + 1 == this.PageCount) ? true : false;
    unmodifiedRowCount = this.Rows.Count;

    if(this.Rows.Count > 0) // Added only this if statement to fix my problem
    {
        for (int rows = this.Rows.Count; rows < this.PageSize; rows++)
        {
            gvRow = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);

            for (int columns = 0; columns < this.Columns.Count; columns++)
            {
                gvRow.Controls.Add(new TableCell());
            }

            this.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(this.Controls[0].Controls.Count - 1, gvRow);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

GridView's are rendered as tables, and to delete spacing simple change the padding between the table colums.  First create a a main css name for the GridView:

`<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="MyGridView" runat="server">`

then in the css change the table colums padding as desired:

```
.MyGridView{
border: none;

}

 .MyGridView tr{
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top;

 }

.MyGridView td{
  vertical-align: top;
 padding-bottom: 0px;

  }
```